# ArrayList for storing objects in Java isn't working when I add objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm currently solving an exercise from https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-6/1-objects-within-objects Exercise: Cargo Hold. I'm supposed to store objects of a class to an `ArrayList` of another class but whenever I use the `this.suitcases.add(suitcase)` method it never adds the object when I print it. How can I fix this? Any help would surely be appreciated. Thanks!

> The program's output should be the following:
>
> > 2 suitcases (7 kg)
>
> My output:
>
> > 0 suitcases (0 kg)

```
public class Hold {
    
    private int minWeight;
    private int maxWeight;
    private ArrayList<Suitcase> suitcases;
    
    public Hold(int maxWeight){
        this.minWeight = 0;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
        this.suitcases = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addSuitcase(Suitcase suitcase){
        if(suitcase.totalWeight() + minWeight >= maxWeight){
            minWeight = minWeight + suitcase.totalWeight();
            this.suitcases.add(suitcase);
        }
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return this.suitcases.size() + " suitcases (" + minWeight + " kg)";
    }
}
```

```
public class Suitcase {

    private int maxWeight;
    private int minWeight;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public Suitcase(int maxWeight) {
        this.minWeight = 0;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {

        if (minWeight + item.getWeight() <= maxWeight) {
            minWeight = minWeight + item.getWeight();
            this.items.add(item);
        }
    }

    public void printItems() {
        for (Item item : this.items) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

    public Item heaviestItem() {
        if (this.items.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        Item returnObject = this.items.get(0);

        for (Item i : this.items) {
            if (returnObject.getWeight() < i.getWeight()) {
                returnObject = i;
            }
        }

        return returnObject;

    }

    public int totalWeight() {
        return minWeight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.items.isEmpty()) {
            return "no items (0kg)";
        }
        if (this.items.size() == 1) {
            return this.items.size() + " item (" + minWeight + " kg)";
        }

        return this.items.size() + " items (" + minWeight + " kg)";
    }
}
```

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int weight;
    
    public Item(String name, int weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public int getWeight(){
        return this.weight;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + " (" + this.weight + " kg)";
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // You can use the main to test your classes!
        Item book = new Item("Lord of the rings", 2);
        Item phone = new Item("Nokia 3210", 1);
        Item brick = new Item("brick", 4);

        Suitcase adasCase = new Suitcase(10);
        adasCase.addItem(book);
        adasCase.addItem(phone);

        Suitcase pekkasCase = new Suitcase(10);
        pekkasCase.addItem(brick);

        Hold hold = new Hold(1000);
        hold.addSuitcase(adasCase);
        hold.addSuitcase(pekkasCase);

        System.out.println(hold);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `suitcase.totalWeight() + minWeight >= maxWeight` should be `suitcase.totalWeight() + minWeight <= maxWeight`

Comment: So it was just a typo :/ I've been staring at it for so long now.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the exercise question just based solely on your code, your problem lies in your condition at hold or specifically at addSuitcases

```
public void addSuitcase(Suitcase suitcase){
if(suitcase.totalWeight() + minWeight >= maxWeight){
    minWeight = minWeight + suitcase.totalWeight();
    this.suitcases.add(suitcase);
}
```

}

It should be

```
public void addSuitcase(Suitcase suitcase){
if(suitcase.totalWeight() + minWeight <= maxWeight){
    minWeight = minWeight + suitcase.totalWeight();
    this.suitcases.add(suitcase);
}
```

}

Since you want to add any item that does not overload the suitcase.

Simply put, change ">=" to "<=" and you should get

> 2 suitcases (7 kg)

Comment: its always good to go through the question, understand and then answer please.